Conditional formatting on a matrix in powerbi
I have columns in a matrix that display sales data for sales employees and shows the sum of their data for a number of years. I wanted to make the visual easier to read by using conditional formatting. I want the yearly data for employees to look at the column to its left and then colour code depending on whether there is an increase or decrease in sales.
I tried measures but when I add them to the table it adds the measure I made for one year to all the years so the matrix becomes unnecessarily wide.

Can you add a screenshot or example of what the matrix looks like? More information about how the data is structured would also be helpful

You need to do something like:
VAR ThisYear = YEAR(MAX(Date[TheYear]))
VAR LastYear = ThisYear - 1
VAR SalesTY = CALCULATE([Measure1], DateTable[TheYear] = ThisYear)
VAR SalesLY = CALCULATE([Measure1], DateTable[TheYear] = LastYear)
RETURN
IF(SalesTY > SalesLY, 1, 0)

That assumes measure1 = sum(Table[Sales]) and you have a date table with years. If you don't have a date table, you can use power query to create one easily from a list of dates. This has to be marked as a date table.
Then find conditional formatting features in the the formatting tab, select the measure above, and then set the parameters for coloring. In the above case it would be when condition SalesTY > SalesLY = 1.
Importantly, each cell in the visual applies a filter on the row and the column. So if you take the maximum date of the sales measure for some employee in some year, the maximum year will be the year on the column.


See also: Microsoft Learn - Formatting Pane
